# How can I "restore" data in DB after start Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I **"restore"** data in DB after start Spring boot?

For example - when my server shutdown, some rows remain in `NEW` status. I need change status to another, when start server. The first thing that comes to mind is to call the method in `@PostConstruct`:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
   someService.prepareForExecution();
}
```

But it seems to me wrong. I can also run another Sheduller which will be updated.

But I must be sure that before the server starts up, all data will be restored to normal. how to do it right?

Comment: "some rows" is very unclear to me

Answer (score 2):

I would use an EventListener

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void applicationReady() {
     someService.prepareForExecution();
}
```

Read more about the Events here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners